# How can I use emacs instead of Ubuntu SDK to write Ubuntu Touch Apps?

Tags: development, ubuntu-sdk, emacs

I want to use emacs and console tools instead of Ubuntu SDK to edit and debug my projects.
Where can I learn about doing that?

Comment: I'd suggest installing the SDK, and looking carefully at what it does. Nothing precludes your using the one true editor on files that you then let the SDK build. Or, you could enter the wonderful wonderful world of emacs customization through writing Lisp programs, or hope some other Ubuntu Touch developer has.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can! The SDK is meant to make it a bit easier, but nothing prevents you from doing it yourself (and perhaps making it a step in your CI environment). Michael Zanetti wrote up a blog post about it [here](http://notyetthere.org/on-manually-creating-click-packages/).